# Python: Nose not picking up new test

Tags: python, nose

I have just added a unit test to one of my Python modules that nose is refusing to pick up. The test looks like this:

```
class TestMargin(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def test_margin(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

I would expect this test to fail but it seems it's not even picked up. I am running nose with the `--all-modules` flag, and tests in other modules are indeed being picked up so it doesn't seem to be a generic problem with nose. I have checked the documentation of nose and can't see any good reason why this test shouldn't work...

EDIT: I fixed the problem by (somewhat haphazardly) adding an empty `__init__.py` at the level of the module. But why would this help?

Comment: I'm guessing the module isn't being included somehow. Brutally you could put a print statement at the top of it to double check - though nose probably has a tidier way of printing all the included modules!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test looks fine, but you have to place it in the right place in the right filename in order for nose to discover it.

You can see the inner working of nose by running it with `-vvv`

By default nose makes decision whether to descent into your directory structure by checking two things: is it a package? if yes, nose will keep looking into directory for more tests. And being [a package in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) means having `__init__.py` file. That is why adding `__init__.py` fixed the issue.

If the directory is not a package, nose may still want to look into it, if it looks like a test directory, i.e. `tests` or if it looks like a source directory, i.e. `src` or `lib`. But I guess that was not the case.

Have a look at [nose usage documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#extended-usage):

> Any python source file, directory or package that matches the testMatch regular expression (by default: (?:^|[b_.-])[Tt]est) will be collected as a test (or source for collection of tests). In addition, all other **packages** found in the working directory will be examined for python source files or directories that match testMatch. Package discovery descends all the way down the tree, so package.tests and package.sub.tests and package.sub.sub2.tests will all be collected.

Also, nose is just a bunch of python files, so you can always look into code to see how it discovers tests. In this case, you may want to look into [wantDirectory()](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/selector.py#L83) method in selector.py

Answer (score 1):

If your naming is proper and still file is not getting picked one of the possible reasons is your test file has executable permission on it -rwxrwxr-x. Modify the permissions to -rw-rw-r--. Python Nose does not pick files with executable permissions.

In case executable flag is added by mistake to version control remove permissions as follows

### Git

Find permissions via

```
git ls-files --stage | grep file_name
```

Remove execute permission and then commit

```
git update-index --chmod=-x file_path
```

### SVN

If svn Properties are present can be listed via

```
svn proplist test_file_path
```

Property Deletion

```
svn propdel svn:executable test_file_path
```